# How to prepend extra 0s unto calculated binary digits

Tags: pgfmath

So I'm suppose to make an omega network that connects 0010 to 1000 and I have pretty much done it, however I would like to display my binary with extra zeros.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{sa-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{module size=0.6cm,pin length factor=0.6,
module ysep=1.0, module xsep=3.5}

\begin{tikzpicture}[P=16]

\node[banyan omega={module label opacity=0}] {};
\newcounter{portb}
\setcounter{portb}{0}
\foreach \module in {1,...,8}{
\foreach \port in {1,...,2}{
\stepcounter{portb}
\pgfmathbin{\theportb-1}
\node[left] at (r0-\module-front input-\port)
{\scriptsize{\pgfmathresult}};
\node[right] at (r4-\module-front output-\port)
{\scriptsize{\pgfmathresult}};
}
}
\draw[red,ultra thick] (r0-2-front input-1) -- (r0-2-front output-1)--
(r1-3-front input-1) -- (r1-3-front output-2)-- (r2-6-front input-1)--
(r2-6-front output-1) -- (r3-3-front input-2) -- (r3-3-front output-1)--
(r4-5-front input-1) -- (r4-5-front output-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output Image]

How can I display 10_2 as (0010)_2, brackets not needed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expl3` makes it easy :)

I adapted some code of a package I'm (forever) writing.

I defined a command `\PrependZeros[<this many>]{<string>}` which adds zeros to the left of the `<string>` until it is `<this many>` characters long. The number of zeros is optional and, if not given, the value in `\g_fleet_number_of_zeros` will be used. You can change the value of `\g_fleet_number_of_zeros` using `\SetZeros{<this many>}`.

The function does a full (`e`-type) expansion of the argument before counting the number of characters, so you can safely pass `\pgfmathresult` to it.

Here I used `\SetZeros{4}` and `\PrependZeros[5]{\pgfmathresult}` to demonstrate:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \g_fleet_number_of_zeros
\NewDocumentCommand\SetZeros{m}
  {
    \int_gset:Nn \g_fleet_number_of_zeros {#1}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\PrependZeros{om}
  {
    \IfValueTF{#1}
      { \__fleet_count:ne {#1} {#2} }
      { \__fleet_count:ne {\g_fleet_number_of_zeros} {#2} }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__fleet_count:nn #1#2
  {
    \exp_args:Nf \__fleet_prepend:nn
      { \int_max:nn { #1 - \str_count:n {#2} } { 0 } }
      {#2}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__fleet_count:nn { ne }
\cs_new:Npn \__fleet_prepend:nn #1#2
  { \prg_replicate:nn {#1}{0} #2 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{sa-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{module size=0.6cm,pin length factor=0.6,
module ysep=1.0, module xsep=3.5}

\begin{tikzpicture}[P=16]
\SetZeros{4}
\node[banyan omega={module label opacity=0}] {};
\newcounter{portb}
\setcounter{portb}{0}
\foreach \module in {1,...,8}{
\foreach \port in {1,...,2}{
\stepcounter{portb}
\pgfmathbin{\theportb-1}
\node[left] at (r0-\module-front input-\port)
{\scriptsize{\PrependZeros{\pgfmathresult}}};
\node[right] at (r4-\module-front output-\port)
{\scriptsize{\PrependZeros[5]{\pgfmathresult}}};
}
}
\draw[red,ultra thick] (r0-2-front input-1) -- (r0-2-front output-1)--
(r1-3-front input-1) -- (r1-3-front output-2)-- (r2-6-front input-1)--
(r2-6-front output-1) -- (r3-3-front input-2) -- (r3-3-front output-1)--
(r4-5-front input-1) -- (r4-5-front output-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple macro with `expl3`, which is fully expandable (at the expense of efficiency, but it's not really so heavy).

The binary number is generated twice, one for counting the number of digits and add the necessary padding zeros; by default `\pbinary{<number>}` pads to four digits, whereas `\pbinary[10]{<number>}` will print ten digits. If the number is longer than specified, it will be printed as is.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{sa-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\pbinary}{O{4}m}
 {% #1 = optional number of digits, default 4
  % #2 = integer to convert
  \grandfleet_binary:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \grandfleet_binary:nn
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn
   {
    \int_max:nn { 0 } { #1 - \str_count:f { \int_to_bin:n { #2 } } }
   }
   { 0 }
  \int_to_bin:n { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_count:n { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\tikzset{
  module size=0.6cm,
  pin length factor=0.6,
  module ysep=1.0,
  module xsep=3.5
}

\newcounter{portb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[P=16]

\node[banyan omega={module label opacity=0}] {};
  \setcounter{portb}{0}
  \foreach \module in {1,...,8}{
    \foreach \port in {1,...,2}{
      \stepcounter{portb}
      \node[left] at (r0-\module-front input-\port)
        {\scriptsize\pbinary{\value{portb}-1}};
      \node[right] at (r4-\module-front output-\port)
        {\scriptsize\pbinary[5]{\value{portb}}};
    }
  }
  \draw[red,ultra thick]
    (r0-2-front input-1) -- (r0-2-front output-1) --
    (r1-3-front input-1) -- (r1-3-front output-2) --
    (r2-6-front input-1) -- (r2-6-front output-1) --
    (r3-3-front input-2) -- (r3-3-front output-1) --
    (r4-5-front input-1) -- (r4-5-front output-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that you can specify an integer expression in the argument to `\pbinary`.

[image]

The operation might be

```
\int_max:nn { 0 } { #1 - \fp_eval:n { max(0,floor(ln(#2)/ln(2),0))+1 } }
```

but I doubt it's more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody waited for me.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{sa-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{xintbinhex}
\usepackage{bnumexpr}

% expandable macro
\catcode`: 11 \catcode`_ 11
% \paddedbinary[#1]{#2}
% #1 = optional number of digits, default 4
% #2 = integer to convert (or any input expanding to such an integer
%      the integer is not limited in size
\newcommand{\paddedbinary}{}
\def\paddedbinary#1{\romannumeral\paddedbinary_chkopt#1\xint:}%
\def\paddedbinary_chkopt #1%
{%
    \ifx [#1\expandafter\paddedbinary_opt
    \else\expandafter\paddedbinary_noopt
    \fi #1%
}%
\def\paddedbinary_opt [\xint:#1]%
{%
    \expandafter\paddedbinary_opt_a\the\numexpr #1.%
}%
\def\paddedbinary_opt_a #1.#2%
{%
    \expandafter\paddedbinary_post\romannumeral0\xintdectobin{\thebnumexpr#2\relax}.#1.%
}%
\def\paddedbinary_noopt #1\xint:
{%
    \expandafter\paddedbinary_post\romannumeral0\xintdectobin{\thebnumexpr#1\relax}.4.%
}%
\def\paddedbinary_post#1.#2.%
{%
    \xintreplicate{#2-\xintLength{#1}}{0}#1%
}%
\catcode`: 12
\catcode`_ 8

\tikzset{
  module size=0.6cm,
  pin length factor=0.6,
  module ysep=1.0,
  module xsep=3.5
}

\newcounter{portb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[P=16]

\node[banyan omega={module label opacity=0}] {};
  \setcounter{portb}{0}
  \foreach \module in {1,...,8}{
    \foreach \port in {1,...,2}{
      \stepcounter{portb}
      \node[left] at (r0-\module-front input-\port)
        {\scriptsize\paddedbinary{\value{portb}-1}};
      \node[right] at (r4-\module-front output-\port)
        {\scriptsize\paddedbinary[5]{\value{portb}}};
    }
  }
  \draw[red,ultra thick]
    (r0-2-front input-1) -- (r0-2-front output-1) --
    (r1-3-front input-1) -- (r1-3-front output-2) --
    (r2-6-front input-1) -- (r2-6-front output-1) --
    (r3-3-front input-2) -- (r3-3-front output-1) --
    (r4-5-front input-1) -- (r4-5-front output-1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 1) node {$138718927*3173198791=\thebnumexpr138718927*3173198791\relax$};
  \draw (0,0) node {${}=\paddedbinary[64]{138718927*3173198791}_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]